# Xml Reader C# to PHP

Tags: php, xml

Im use this code for reader the xml value on C#

```
XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
            doc1.Load("http://apps.db.ripe.net/whois/search.xml?query-string=" + textBox1.Text + "&source=ripe");
            descr_1 = doc1.SelectSingleNode("/whois-resources/objects/object[@type=\"route\"]/attributes/attribute[@name=\"descr\"]");
```

now i need the same value on php, it is possibile?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php + http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php, http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php + http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

Answer (score 0):

How php handle html form data is also a bit different so I didn't put the textBox1 here, but you should be able to find that out easily.

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement("http://apps.db.ripe.net/whois/search.xml", NULL, TRUE);
$sxe->xpath("/whois-resources/objects/object[@type=\"route\"]/attributes/attribute[@name=\"descr\"]");
```